# Prove uniqueness of the minimum of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that $\{B_i\}$ is a positive and strictly decreasing sequence, without any other knowledge about it, such as whether $\sum_{i=1}^N B_i$ converges or not.

Let $N\in \{1,2,...,J\}$ for some $J\in\mathbb{N}_+$, show that for $0<a<1$, there exists a unique $N$ that minimizes $A_N=\frac{N^{a}}{\sum_{i=1}^N B_i}$.

I ran some simulations in Matlab, and it appears $A_N$ is quite well-behaved: depending on the value of $\{B_i\}$ and $a$, $A_N$ can be: 1. monotone increasing; 2. monotone decreasing and approaching some non-negative lower bound; or 3. first decreasing then increasing.

The simulations tell me that with $N$ being in a bounded set, it's promising that we can prove the uniqueness of the minimizer. Appreciate any help.

I also figured that for discrete problems, in very rare cases, we will have 2 minimizers even if the continuous counterpart has a unique minimizer.

Comment: As a quick note, since $B_i$ is monotone decreasing and bounded below by 0, you do indeed know it converges.

Comment: Hi Alan, you are right, I should say we don't know whether $\sum_{i=1}^N B_i$ converges or not.

Comment: This seems simply false. Take $J=2$ and $a=\frac12$ and $\{B_1,B_2\}=\{1,\sqrt2-1\}$ for example. Indeed, given $a$, the $B_i$ can be chosen so that all the $A_N$ are equal.